# Repopulating Image Picker select control with new data after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, picker

I am using this Image Picker jQuery plugin (http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) and I'm facing a problem with the following:

Repopulating the select control with new data after ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: requestURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result)
    {
       $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
       console.log(obj.description);
       $('#cake-filling-types-select')
          .append($("<option data-img-src='" + obj.image + "'></option>")                                         
           .attr("value", obj.code)
           .text(obj.description));
    });
    $("#cake-filling-types-select").imagepicker({
       show_label  : true
    });

    $("#cake-filling-types-select").data("picker").sync_picker_with_select();
}});
```

For more details please find the issue here: https://github.com/rvera/image-picker/issues/79

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. With the help of @ArmindoMaurits @ GitHub, so using the ' $("#cake-filling-types-select").empty();' is fine for clearing this plugin select.

Also, for the other issue where some items are not getting into the select control, I found that these the ones that is missing the img src.

Updated working code:

```
      `$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: requestURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){

               $("#cake-filling-types-select").empty();

                $.each(result, function(i, obj) {

                    if(obj.image != null)
                    {
                        var imgSrc = obj.image;
                    }else{
                        imgSrc = '';
                    }

           $('#cake-filling-types-select')
              .append($("<option data-img-src='" + imgSrc + "'></option>")
                      .attr("value", obj.code)
                       .text(obj.description));
                });

                $("#cake-filling-types-select").imagepicker({
                    show_label  : true
                });

            }});`
```